# .net core hosted in Linux server shows system environment value as null

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core

I am hosting .net core application in Linux Server, wherein I have configured the DB connection string to be read from System Environment variables. It works well in windows OS but when I run the same code in Linux Server, it says "Value cannot be null" for the Environment variable

I have configured an Environment variable in Linux Server with the name "default". I am able to print the value in `Console.WriteLine(Configuration.GetConnectionString("default")).` 
   But when the the same value is used in `UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("default")),` 
it throws `"Value cannot be null" error.`

However, if I hard code the value in UseSqlServer method, it is able to identify and proceed ahead.

For instance,

```
default = "Server=X;Database=y;User Id=A;Password=P"

Console.WriteLine(Configuration.GetConnectionString("default")) -> "Prints the value".

UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("default"))
```

Throws `"Value cannot be null"`

Note :  It works in Windows, but not in Linux.

I read few articles which state to use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("default", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)`, but again this works in windows and not in Linux.

Comment: It sound like you are running a service in windows and connecting from Linux.  A windows service is not running with any environmental variables.  You can right click the service application and change to "Run As".

Comment: Its a web application, not a windows service. secondly, I am hosting the application in Linux server, which requires DB connection string to be read from the preconfigured Environment variable. Linux server is unable to read the value of environment variable

Comment: Read following : https://codeburst.io/linux-environment-variables-53cea0245dc9

Comment: Do you set the connection string in appsettings.json instead of appsettings.Development.json?

Comment: I set it in Environment variable and try to access from there by using the AddEnvironmentVariable() method which takes care to compulsorly read values from EV in .netcore

Comment: @jdweng, the link you shared doesn't help the cause. any other articles? i looked for a lot of them but found none.

Comment: So if you store `Configuration.GetConnectionString("default")` in a variable and then pass it to `Console.WriteLine()` it shows the correct string, but if you pass it to `UseSqlServer()` doesn't? That doesn't make much sense... a string is a string, and it doesn't matter if it comes from the environment or anywhere else. If it works for one method, it should work for the other, so there's something you have either explained wrong on the question, or you are not telling us

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too.  If you are running a .Net Core Web Api like I am on Linux under a systemctl daemon service, you have to store the Environment Variable on the service settings.

`cd /etc/systemd/system`

`sudo nano my-app-name.service`

Update the service section, note the last lines:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/my-app-site
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/my-app-site/my-app.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=my-app
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
```

followed by

`systemctl daemon-reload`

followed by

`sudo systemctl restart my-app-name.service`